# Storing intermediate data in a file in Perl 6

Tags: raku

Some of my programs consist of two parts. First, they read large data from files and transform it, producing `Array`s, `Hash`es, `Object`s etc.; second, they analyse this data with (always different) user-defined conditions. The first part remains the same (as long as the source data isn't changed), but sometimes it takes considerable time to work every time I run the program, and I usually have to run it many times with the same source data. It would be much better to have two programs — one of them (once) reads the data and transforms it, while the other analyses it (many times).

My question is: what's the best way to store those `Array`s, `Hash`es and `Object`s, so that the first program writes them to a file and the second one reads them from that file?

Comment: JSON? The Object mapping might be the major issue but it's a simple format for storing data that allows for the various parts of be written in different languages. Personally unless I'm doing something complex these days I reach for JSON as my data storage option of choice.

Comment: @raiph It reads the data from files and then collects statistics and transform it for subsequent analysis. As for Memory-mapped-file, I'd prefer something more simple :) 
I run the programs on a typical 3-year-old laptop. I'm not sure that my program can be easily parallelize.

Scimon I've thought about JSON, but I've never used it, so I'm not sure whether it fits my requirements. Probably I have to learn this format.

Answer (score 5):

You can write the data structure to a Perl 6 source file and "use" it, then it'll be pre-compiled for you, which is potentially the fastest way to get a data structure into a Perl 6 program.

Other than that, JSON has some notable limitations that native Perl 6 data structures don't have, like the difference between integers and floating point numbers, and support for Inf, -Inf and NaN. There's also no support for keys in objects that are "complex", i.e. no arrays as hash keys.

One example serialization format that supports most of what Perl 6 can throw at it is MessagePack. There's modules for it already, I have only used Data::MessagePack so far, but here's the list: https://modules.perl6.org/search/?q=messagepack

Comment: +Inf. (SO doesn't allow comments less than 15 characters and we're supposed to add value to a question or answer in these comments, not just say "wow, what a perfect answer".)

Comment: @timotimo Could you explain in more details what you said in the 1st paragraph? How should I write to a p6 source file?

Comment: Try `.perl` method.