# Perl6 equivalent of Perl's 'store' or 'use Storable'

Tags: raku

I am attempting to write a hash, which is written very slowly, into a data file, but am unsure about how Perl6 does this in comparison to Perl5.  This is a similar question [Storing intermediate data in a file in Perl 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830372/storing-intermediate-data-in-a-file-in-perl-6) but I don't see how I can use anything written there, specifically messagepack.

I'd like to see the Perl6 equivalent of

```
my %hash = ( 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4);
use Storable;
store \%hash, 'hash.pldata';
```

and then read with

```
my $hashref = retrieve('hash.pldata');
my %hash = %{ $hashref };
```

This is built in to Perl5, it's super easy,  I don't need to install any modules (I love it!), but how can I do this in Perl6? I don't see it in the manual.  They appear to be talking about something else with `STORE` https://docs.perl6.org/routine/STORE

Comment: Storable *is* a module, and your example uses it quite explicitly: ‘use Storable’. This conflicts with the statement “I don't need to use any modules”

Comment: If there were such a module it might be used something like `my %hash is Storable::Hash['filename']`.

Comment: @BradGilbert for future development, I think it would be great to add something like `@giant-array.store('array_data.p6data')` or `%giant-hash.store('hash_data.p6data')` or something like that to Perl6.

Comment: @ugexe I've clarified that I don't need to *install* any modules, sorry about that

Comment: I would recommend JSON or YAML for data serialization.

Comment: Storable has tons of problems X_X

Comment: @ikegami what kind of problems?

Comment: So I just did a quick test. Made a hash with 1000 key/values pairs. Used Perl5 storable and the output file is 15476 bytes. Then I made the same file and output it as a pretty printed json file. 14344 bytes. 
So a JSON file is cross langauge compatible, future proof and smaller than a Storable file.

Comment: I was addressing a similar but not exact problem with [`Redis::Objects`](https://github.com/CurtTilmes/perl6-eredis#redisobjects-perlish-objects-tied-to-redis-objects).

Comment: You can just use many Perl 5 modules as is in Perl 6. You can, for example, just write `use Storable:from<Perl5>;` and then use it using Perl 6 syntax. You may have to do something to turn this ability on such as letting Perl 6 know where your Perl 5 modules are installed and perhaps installing whatever extra Perl 5 modules you want. To find out where things are at on your system, just try typing the `use` line as I've written it above and seeing what the compiler says. For more info see https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5/blob/master/README.md If you get stuck, post another SO question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this? OK, not as efficient as `Storable` but it seems to work....

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl6
my $hash_ref = {
    array  => [1, 2, 3],
    hash   => { a => 1, b => 2 },
    scalar => 1,
};

# store
my $fh = open('dummy.txt', :w)
    or die "$!\n";
$fh.print( $hash_ref.perl );
close($fh)
    or die "$!\n";

# retrieve
$fh = open('dummy.txt', :r)
    or die "$!\n";
my $line = $fh.get;
close($fh)
    or die "$!\n";

my $new_hash_ref;
{
    use MONKEY-SEE-NO-EVAL;
    $new_hash_ref = EVAL($line)
        or die "$!\n";
}

say "OLD: $hash_ref";
say "NEW: $new_hash_ref";

exit 0;
```

I get this

```
$ perl6 dummy.pl
OLD: array      1 2 3
hash    a       1
b       2
scalar  1
NEW: array      1 2 3
hash    a       1
b       2
scalar  1
```

Comment: while I appreciate your work, I was hoping for a system approach, like `use Storable` in Perl5, which I could type as quickly as I could in the question.  It looks like it doesn't exist in Perl6 :( I wonder how I can contribute to Perl6

Answer (score 2):

While these do not directly match Storable, there are a couple of approaches outlined at:

- http://perl6maven.com/data-serialization-with-json-in-perl6
- https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2018/12/15/day-15-building-a-spacecraft-with-perl-6/

Another option for simple objects is to use .perl to 'store' then EVAL to 'read' ... from https://docs.perl6.org/routine/perl

```
> Returns a Perlish representation of the object (i.e., can usually be
> re-evaluated with EVAL to regenerate the object).
```

Answer (score 2):

I seriously think you should move away from Storable and over to JSON. If you're using Rakudo Star as your install it includes a number of different JSON modules as part of it's core install so you don't need to add anything extra.

JSON is compatible with a number of different languages (not just Perl) and is a defined standard (unlike Storable which is backward incompatible). And JSON file sizes are of a similar size (if not smaller).

About the only plus point of Storable over JSON is handling code references. But if you're just storing data I wouldn't advise using Storable.